# Rails: N+1 problem... statistical data needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, statistics

After realizing that an application suffer of the N+1 problem because the ORM, I would like to have more information about the improvements that can be performed and the statistics with the time compared before the improvements (with the N+1 problem) and after. 
**So what is the time difference before and after such improvements ?**
 Can anyone give me a link to some paper that analyze the problem and retrieve statisics on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need statistical data for this, just math. N+1 (or better 1+N) stands for

- 1 query to get a record, and
- N queries to get all records associated with it

The bigger N is, the more a performance hit this becomes, particularly if your queries are sent across the network to a remote database. That's why N+1 problems keep cropping up in production - they're usually insignificant in development mode with little data in the DB, but as your data grows in production to thousands or millions of rows, your queries will slowly choke your server.

You can instead use

- a single query (via a join) or
- 2 queries (one for the primary record, one for all associated records

The first query will return more data than strictly needed (the data of the first record will be duplicated in each row), but that's usually a good tradeoff to make. The second query might get a bit cumbersome for large data sets since all foreign keys are passed in as a single range, but again, it's usually a tradeoff worth making.

The actual numbers depend on too many variables for statistics to be meaningful. Number or records, DB version, hardware etc. etc.

Since you tagged this question with rails, ActiveRecord does a good job avoiding N+1 queries if you know how to use it. Check out the explanation of [eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

The time difference would depend on how many additional selects were performed because of the N+1 problem. Here's a quote from an answer given to another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) regarding N+1 -

Quote Start

```
SELECT * FROM Cars;

/* for each car */
SELECT * FROM Wheel WHERE CarId = ?
```

In other words, you have one select for the Cars, and then N additional selects, where N is the total number of cars.

Quote End

In the example above the time difference would depend on how many car records were in the database and how long it took to query the 'Wheel' table each time the code/ORM fetched a new record. If you only had 2 car records then the difference after removing the N+1 problem would be negligible, but if you have a million car records then it would have a significant affect.